# First-order initial-value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider this first-order initial value problem:

$$\begin{cases}
y'=1-x+y^2-xy^2\\
y(0)=1
\end{cases}$$

I've tried simplifying the right-hand side to $(y^2+1)(-x+1)$ and then integrating it.

I obtained a general solution as a tangent function but it seems that this is not the answer.

Comment: What solution did you get?  The solution to this problem can be written as a tangent, but can also be written in other forms.

Comment: Your wording makes it seem that you provided a general solution to a question asking for a particular solution (since it provides an initial condition), which is evidently  the incorrect form of an answer.  Alternatively, you generated a general form using tangent and find the value for the constant of integration to satisfy the initial condition and that answer is declared incorrect.  Which is it, and in either case, what answer did you get; we can't just guess that you integrated correctly.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title—one that will help attract solvers and help later folks find the solution.  Your title applies to hundreds of thousands of problems.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I obtained y = tan(-x²/2+x+c). Then with the initial condition I obtained c as pi/4.

Comment: @EricTowers With the general solution obtained, I got a particular solution as y = tan(-x²/2+x+pi/4). Would this be a wrong approach?

Comment: You comment that you obtained $y=\tan(-x^2/2+x+C)$ but you should be [edit]ing your question to fill not only this information but how you obtained it.

Answer (score 3):

Your general solution is right.
$$y = \tan\left(x-\dfrac{x^2}2+c\right)$$
Satisfying $(0,1)$, we get,
$$1=\tan c\implies c=n\pi+\dfrac\pi4\\
\implies y=\tan\left(x-\dfrac{x^2}2+n\pi+\dfrac\pi4\right)\\
=\tan\left(x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac\pi4\right)$$
To verify, we differentiate both sides,
$$\implies y' = \sec^2\left(x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac\pi4\right)(1-x)$$
(by chain rule)
$$\implies y' = \left(1+\tan^2\left(x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac\pi4\right)\right)(1-x)\\
=(1+y^2)(1-x)$$
which is the desired original differential equation.

Comment: How did you do to obtain the result for the chain rule? I keep getting $$ 2 \sec^2x( -\frac{x^2}{2}+x+ \frac{ \pi}{4})tan( -\frac{x^2}{2}+x+ \frac{ \pi}{4})(-x+1)   $$

Comment: @Santi, by chain rule, we get, $\frac{d(\tan u)}{dx} = {\sec^2u}\times\frac{du}{dx}$

Comment: by applying Chain Rule on $$   \sec^2 (x- \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4})  $$ I get $$  \frac{du}{dx} \frac{1}{ \tan u} =2 \sec^2{u} \times \frac{du}{dx}     $$, placing u as $$  x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{ \pi }{4}      $$

Comment: @Santi, no, you are not only wrongly differentiating, but also differentiating that which is not required to be differentiated. We need to differentiate, $\tan u$, since that is our $y$, why are you differentiating $\sec^2u$?

Comment: I thought that we had to apply Chain Rule to $$  \sec ^2 u $$. Then we just differentiate tan u to obtain $$  1 +  \tan^2 x(x- \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{\pi}{4})    $$?

Comment: @Santi, no that is not the case. We have $y=\tan u$, differentiate both sides to obtain $y' = (\sec^2u)\frac{du}{dx} = (1+\tan^2u)(1-x)=(1+y^2)(1-x)$ which is the original differential equation. Since this function satisfies the original differential equation, it is verified to be a correct solution.

Comment: I got the concept and the right answer @Martund. Thank you!

Comment: @Santi, Thank You comments are deprecated by stackexchange community. If you find this answer helpful and it solved your problem then you should click on the check mark to accept it and/or upvote it.